# How do I decode a string from base 32 to a BigInteger

Tags: java, biginteger, base32

I tried the following code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base32;
import org.junit.Test;

public class Sandbox
{
  @Test
  public void testSomething() {
    String sInput = "GIYTINZUHAZTMNBX";

    BigInteger bb = new BigInteger(new Base32().decode(sInput));

    System.out.println("number = " + bb);
  }
}
```

and heres the output:

```
number = 237025977136523702055991
```

using [this website to convert between base 32](http://online-calculators.appspot.com/base32/) I get a different result than the actual output. Heres the result I expect to see based on what I got from the website:

```
expected output = 2147483647
```

Any idea why this is happening?

**Edit:**

Forgive me for making it confusing by purposefully attempting to convert 2^31-1.

Using the conversion website I linked to earlier, I changed the input:

```
String sInput = "GE4DE===";
```

Expected output:

```
number = 182
```

Actual output:

```
number = 3225650
```

Comment: That site is spitting out 2^31-1 so I highly suspect they internally do 32 bits signed math, and of course overflow.  Without actually calculating anything I'd say the result you're getting looks a whole lot more like a reasonable result than 2^31-1

Comment: Not a real question. None of the strings you have posted is in base-32 radix. That last one looks like base-64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is correct... **assuming that the Base32 string comes from Base32-encoding a byte array you get from calling** `BigInteger.toByteArray()`.

`BigInteger(byte[] val)` does not really take an array of arbitrary bytes.  It takes the `byte[]` representation of a `BigInteger`.  Also, it assumes the most-significant byte is in `val[0]`).

Answer (score 0):

If it's base-32 the X, Y, and Z shouldn't be there. Are you sure it isn't base-36?